# How to Access a Moving Portion of an Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm at a loss for what to do in my program (written in C). There is a large matrix of numbers (an image) that I am processing. The processing happens one line at a time, with reference to the previous line, so *I only need to access two lines of numbers at a time.*

Originally, I tried a 2 by X array but once I save the information for the third line, the array is upside down with the third line of the image in the first row of the array and the second line of the image in the second row of the image.

Is there a better way to correct this other than simply copying the second row of the array to the first row? Maybe it wouldn't be so bad, but I would imagine doing that for every other line of the image would be expensive. Should I use two pointers on the image instead?

I apologize if this is a common thing that can be easily looked up but I couldn't figure out how to begin looking. If anyone needs clarification, let me know. Thank you very much!

Diagram of what numbers I need access to:
http://www.gliffy.com/go/publish/5968966

Comment: if this is image processing can you post the image too.

Comment: @Ben, the image should be irrelavant

Comment: I'm testing various ones. It is irrelevant though because it is literally just a matrix of numbers. You can swap out the word image for anything. I'm looking for help on the general idea of how to store two lines of stuff, by adding one line to the storage device at a time. Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: @Nick, do you need to edit the image?

Comment: perhaps I should say a diagram of what it is you're trying to do, it was really confusing at first. Now I see that you want to iterate through an array row-wise, but you're scanning two rows at once. Could you go into more detail about what you want, and why is it you feel the need to copy these two rows into a buffer.

Comment: Nope, only need to do calculations with the numbers and then write my new image. I currently have the image stored in a header file just as an array of the pixels.

EDIT: Ben, I am getting a stack overflow (haha) because I think I am using too much memory. One image is about 4000x3000 so I was looking to slimming down how much memory I use at once. It works correctly on smaller images, but when I use larger ones it runs out. I'm thinking pointers might be the answer, not sure though. I will try to make up a diagram for you guys.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are processing the image as you read it, or as you decompress it, or some such, for if you already had the whole thing in memory in usable form then you would just use that.

I see two reasonably good alternatives:

1. Instead of hard-coding the indices of the earlier and later lines in your 2 by x array, use variables to track which row contains which line.
2. Use a 1-D array for each line, and use pointers to track which one contains the current line and which one contains the previous line.

(Though really, those boil down to pretty much the same thing.)  Either way, you can avoid needless copying.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! You are right in assuming that the processing happens as it is read, there is a decompression portion.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have:

```
struct rbg_t bitmap[X][Y];
```

To get a window of dimensions X by 2, it is like this:

```
struct rgb_t *first_line = bitmap[0], *second_line=bitmap[1];
```

Then you can process the two lines like so:

```
for(int i=0;i<X;++i)
{
    do_work(first_line[i], second_line[i]);
}
```

To shift the window down by one, you can do this:

```
first_line+=sizeof(struct rgb_t)*X;
second_line+=sizeof(struct rgb_t)*X;
```

Where X is the width of the bitmap

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This may work well with the first part of the program.